# Detailed composition of TensorFlow device names?

Tags: tensorflow

What are "suffixes" such as `Allocators`, `Compute`, and `Tensors` in [device names](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/framework/other_functions_and_classes) such as the following:

```
 Allocators
 /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 Compute
 /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 Tensors
```

Are these for processes (or threads) on a given CPU? But then what about the first case, where there is no CPU specified?

BTW, I've seen these examples reported in `timeline.json` (serialized from a [`Timeline`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/client/timeline.py)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if those suffixes are not native to TensorFlow, but artifacts created when it produces a trace in Chrome Trace Format with `Timeline.generate_chrome_trace_format()`.

These are the relevant lines of [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/client/timeline.py#L480-L481):

```
self._chrome_trace.emit_pid(dev_stats.device + ' Compute', device_pid)
self._chrome_trace.emit_pid(dev_stats.device + ' Tensors', tensors_pid)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe one shows the timeline of ops running on your device and the other shows the timeline of tensors running on that device.

Comment: Thx. There is also a 3rd one called `Allocators`.